# Android graphics draw on a canvas question

Tags: android, graphics

I am writing my first android app. So am still in the learning phase.

Its very simple, I draw a graphic in the onDraw() in the center of the screen and with the onTouch event will have to move the graphic to the point where the user touched. For this the onTouch event will start a thread and update the graphic. The problem is the canvas.draw() is working when called from onDraw() but does not update the canvas/screen when called from within the thread.

My function drawSplash( Canvas c, Location l );

I call the same function in both the onDraw() and the thread.

The only difference in the code I can see is I am storing the Canvas object passed in to me in the onDraw() function in a variable in my class so that I can use it in the thread again. This somehow feels wrong. If so, what is the correct way to do this? Can I get the Canvas object anytime I want? How do I do that?

- P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to .invalidate() your view with has the onDraw method overrited. Each time it's called it should draw the Graphics on the right position.

And you should call the .invalidate() method inside the Main Thread.

Comment: Ah. So when I call invalidate() the whole view is destroyed is it? I have to redraw the whole graphic every time to update the splash then?

Comment: When you call invalidate(), the canvas is cleared and the `onDraw` method is called. So `onDraw` should draw everything each time

Comment: @iuliux - This is interesting. Never thought of it before. So if I am creating a chess board then with every move I draw the whole board again? Is that how it normally works? There is no concept of updating the graphic or atleast separating the stuff I want to be updated while keeping the base (like the board here) constant?

Comment: @user220201 Yes, you should repaint all the screen. An game is based on painting it's at least 20 times per second (that is the FPS meter).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different approach.

Make some global fields like this:

```
    private int mX;  
    private int mY;
```

And then, in your `onTouch()` method (you use the `onTouch` of the same `View` class, right?) you change those fields and then call the `invalidate()` method:

```
    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
        mX = event.getX();
        mY = event.getY();
        invalidate();
    }
```

So now, the `onDraw()` method will simply draw your splash to the position (mX, mY).

Comment: Ok. Why do I have to invalidate the view in the first place? That is not clear to me. invalidate() wipes out the canvas right? If so how does it matter whether I call it in the onTouch event or the draw()? They are called one after the other obviously.

Comment: Well, the `invalidate()` method tells the `View` that what it is showing is outdated. Then the View updates itself by redrawing. I am not sure if the following is true, but if you would call each time `onDraw` and not `invalidate()`, the splash would be drawn once again, not moved. You would end up having lots of overlaping splashes on your screen

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding you could set the baseboard as a background image.

If you do that you do not have to constantly redraw it but I am not 100% sure of that.

Have a look at the Lunar Lander code on the Android Dev sight here:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html

Phil

Comment: That would be a good way to go about it. But there are ton of other things that I would like to keep constant like the name of the user and other stuff that is actually drawn on. I will look at this code again.